# Create appendix in Lyx

Tags: lyx, appendices

I am trying to create appendix in Lyx. I use 'Document->Start Appendix Here' just before the beginning of the appendix text, and I can see that the text before the Bibliography is wrapped in an appendix box. However, when I print the document, the text appears the same way as the main body text, i.e. no indication whatsoever that these are part of appendix. Any suggestion what I may have missed? I have also tried inserting '\appendix' before the appendix text, but it doesn't work either.

In addition, how does the section numbering work in appendix? Can I simply organise the sections using the dropdown list

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. What happens and what do you want to be different? The text of an appendix _should_ be the same as the main body. All that really changes in an appendix is that the sections are numbered by letters A,B,C... rather than numbers.

Comment: there is only a difference in the chapter/section headings and the entry Appendix is added to the toc. That's all ...

Answer (score 4):

In my master document I have (in TeXnicCenter):

```
\appendix
\input{Appendix1}
\newpage
\input{Appendix2}
```

etc.
And in my Appendix documents (I am using article class):

```
\section{Name of the Appendix}
\label{sec:Appendix1}
```

And then it appears as Appendix A, Appendix B, etc. in the document and in the TOC.

Comment: If you use `\include` rather than `\input`, then there is no need to manually enter `\newpage` between sections.

Comment: and also, shouldn't it be `\clearpage`?

Comment: instead of? what I said works fine by me, but \include is indeed easier, but I was already using \input (and then \newpage)

Comment: What Juan meant is that you can use `\include{Appendix1}` instead of `\input{Appendix1}\newpage`. Does that help for clarification? (If you want to answer me, use "@Hendrik" in your comment.)